# Calculation from Dynamic array and object

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array of objects **A** and an array **B**

An array of objects A looks like this

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#30 (5) {
    ["kriteria_kode"]=>
    string(2) "C1"
    ["kriteria_bobot"]=>
    string(2) "70"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#31 (5) {
    ["kriteria_kode"]=>
    string(2) "C2"
    ["kriteria_bobot"]=>
    string(2) "30"
  }
}
```

and an array B looks like this

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(5)
    [1]=>
    float(4.7)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    float(4.4)
    [1]=>
    float(4.6)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    float(4.8)
    [1]=>
    float(4.4)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    float(4.7)
    [1]=>
    float(4.65)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    float(4.3)
    [1]=>
    float(4.8)
  }
}
```

I want to produce calculation results from both arrays(A and B) using formula below:

```
Array C[0] = ((Array B[0][0]*Array A[0]->kriteria_bobot)/100) +  ((Array B[0][1]*Array A[1]->kriteria_bobot)/100) 
Array C[0] = ((5*70)/100) + ((4.7*30)/100))
Array C[0] = 3.5 + 1.41
Array C[0] = 4.91
```

The final results should be like

```
C[0] = 4.91
C[1] = 4.46
C[2] = 4.68
C[3] = 4.685
C[4] = 4.45
```

I confused for getting output by doing calculations from objects and arrays

Comment: Can you explain better what calculations you want to do from A and B?

Comment: multiplication, division and addition. like the formula above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple `foreach` loop like this one:

```
foreach($B as $pair){
    $C[] = ($pair[0]*$A[0]->kriteria_bobot)/100 + ($pair[1]*$A[1]->kriteria_bobot)/100;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4.91
    [1] => 4.46
    [2] => 4.68
    [3] => 4.685
    [4] => 4.45
)
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/oR1qI)**

You've asked to make a dynamic stuff for array **A**. I'd like to note you, that **the length of array A must be the same as the length of 1 sub-array from array B**:

```
foreach($B as $pair){
    $tmp = 0;
    foreach($A as $ind=>$ob){
        $tmp += ($pair[$ind]*$ob->kriteria_bobot)/100;
    }
    $C[] = $tmp;
}
```

**[Demo2](https://3v4l.org/DGA3K)**

Comment: I can't use it, because I have a lot of data from Array A. So it's difficult if I have to write one at a time for each element of array A. I only give an example for array A, because if not it will take too long if I have to write it. Can you provide a more dynamic answer for array A?

Comment: @RizalTerrisElvalino, then why you didn't provide this note in your answer? Updated

Comment: ok thanks, let me check it out first. if it's working fine , i'll accept this answer